# IPython notebook in git repository

Tags: python, git, gitlab, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know how I can place my IPython notebook files, into my gitlab repository?

**What I have attempted:** I have opened up the terminal in Ipython notebook, attempted to run git commands, was prompted with "Command not found".

- Also did minor research on a git gist. I'm new to git and programming, in general, any guidance will help!
- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you use git via your regular command line? If so, a work around is to just use your regular command line. However, the jupyter terminal should be able to run git commands.

Also, as a side note, I would recommend ensuring that before you push your notebook to git hub to clear the outputs (via Cell > All Output > Clear, or a pre-commit hook/filter if you prefer automation and don't mind learning more about git https://gist.github.com/minrk/6176788) if you plan to use version control, as otherwise every time the output changes, even is the input stays the same, there will be a large diff. If you plan to just store them and don't care about the version control/diff issue then you can ignore this advice.